# What's the difference between "access aggregation" and "authorization creep"?

Tags: cissp

I'm studying for the CISSP and am getting hung up on some terminology.  Specifically, I'm confused on the difference between **access aggregation** and **authorization creep**.

In both cases, it seems to me that an individual users are gaining more access to more systems. Is access aggregation considered acceptable but authorization creep isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Aggregation** is a condition of many systems and security designs and isn't an inherent problem. But it's something that the admins have to be aware of to prevent **creep**.

**Creep** happens unintentionally and can result in violations in authorised access as a result of **aggregation**.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is correct specifically for CISSP, but where I work the terms mean the following:

**Access Aggregation**
Users gaining more access across more systems, this might be intentional as a result of something like the implementation of single sign on capabilities or unintentional where they are granted new access rights without considering the rights they already have.

**Authorisation Creep**
This is where theres a bit of overlap with access aggregation, its when users are given new, or more expansive, rights without having their old rights revoked.